# Loop a certain amount of times

Tags: redux-observable

I have an action, that gets a payload of `.times`. I want to loop something this many times, I did this:

```
function upAsyncEpic(action$: Observable<Action>, state$: StateObservable<State>): Observable<Action> {
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType(UP_ASYNC),
        delay(1000),
        mapTo(up())
    );
}
```

This will not loop it will only happen once. I want it to loop the "delay" then "mapTo" `action.times` times. I tried this:

```
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType(UP_ASYNC),
        repeat(action => action.times),
        delay(1000),
        mapTo(up())
    );
```

But this did not work. Super brand new to redux-observables, just learning.

Basically what I want is if someone dispatches action `{ type: 'UP_ASYNC', times: 5 }` what should happen is this:

```
            delay(1000),
            mapTo(up())
            delay(1000),
            mapTo(up())
            delay(1000),
            mapTo(up())
            delay(1000),
            mapTo(up())
            delay(1000),
            mapTo(up())
```

Comment: perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511566/how-to-chain-actions-and-epics shows what you need in action? apologies if this approach is for something else.

Comment: Thanks @ocæon but I don't think its what Im looking for. I added a clarifying example to bottom of post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: `repeat()` takes an integer as an argument for the count to repeat.

Signature:

`repeat(count: number): Observable`.
[Documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-repeat).

[Example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/repeat.html) from learnrxjs

Your example will look something like this:

```js
function upAsyncEpic(
  action$: Observable<Action>,
  state$: StateObservable<State>
): Observable<Action> {
  let count = 0;

  const source = action$.pipe(
    ofType(UP_ASYNC),
    map(({ times }) => {
      count = times;
    }),
    delay(1000),
    mapTo(up())
  );

  return source.pipe(repeat(count));
}
```

Comment: It's not working for some reason :( I tried :( Also is there a way to do without the local global? I scoured learnrxjs but couldn't find. :(

Comment: Is it possible to do a single chain like `action$.pipe(ofType(UP_ASYNC).pipe(delay(1000), mapTo(up()), repeat(action => action.times))`

Comment: Firstly, you can't pass a function to repeat. You need to pass an integer. Secondly, what does your `up()` function do? Also, does it throw any error?

Comment: Thanks Haroon, `up()` is a redux action. It returns `{ type: 'UP' }`. It should dispatch these actions.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox link to reproduce the code?

Comment: Thanks @Haroon I think I'm getting real close. In the `mergeMap` here I want to do a delay of 1 before moving onto the next - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-iif-i9qe9p?file=index.ts

Comment: so the code that does what I want is `range(1, 10).pipe(switchMap(v => interval(1000))).subscribe(console.log);` however it keeps going even after 10, which is so weird.

Comment: The interval runs for the infinite number of times. You should be using delay() with repeat()

Comment: Thanks Haroon for sticking with me, may you please show example of code on that.